# Pass Optional Event Handler to Custom Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a custom material-ui button component:

```
type ButtonProps = { disabled: boolean; text: string };

export function CustomButton({ disabled, text }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Button
      type="submit"
      disabled={disabled}
      style={{
        background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
      }}>
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}

<CustomButton
  disabled={
    !formik.values.userId ||
    !formik.values.numberPlate ||
    !formik.values.freeSeats
  }
  text={'Add Vehicle'}
/>
```

On most occasions, I don't need to pass an event handler. But at one particular instance, I need to add `onClick={() => ShowUsers()}`

How can I modify my custom component so that it's optional for me to pass an event handler. I do not modify its use on all other places where I am already using the button.

I tried this:

```
type ButtonProps = { disabled: boolean; text: string, onClick?: () => void; };

// submit button

export function CustomButton({ disabled, text, onClick }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Button
      type="submit"
      disabled={disabled}
      style={{
        background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
      }}>
      {text}
      {onClick}
    </Button>
  );
}

<CustomButton disabled={!searchItem} text={'CHECK'} onClick={ShowUsers()}></CustomButton>
```

but it gives an error on onClick that

```
button.tsx(4, 55): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'
```

Probably some syntax issue.

Comment: You can pass the `onClick` as a prop to your component and set its `defaultProps` in your component to not change its use for old components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can fix your type alias,

```
type ButtonProps = { 
  disabled: boolean;
  text: string
  onClick?: () => void;
};
```

And this is how you can bind the method to your `Button` onClick event. You will need to do a null check as `onClick` is an optional prop.

```
<Button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => (onClick ? onClick() : null)}
  disabled={disabled}
  style={{
    background: '#6c74cc',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  }}>
  {text}
</Button>
```

Comment: But how should I use it inside the component and while calling it? Please see the updated qs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `?` in the props

```
type ButtonProps = { disabled: boolean; text: string ; onClick? : any};
```

Comment: But how should I use it inside the component and while calling it? Please see the updated qs.